# How to make permanent changes to /etc/sudoers

Tags: 20.04, sudo, etc, jenkins

I'm trying to setup a Jenkins job that need to run an executable file under `sudo`

I do

- `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`
- add `jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` at the end of file
- CTRL + X and confirm file save prompt

After that when I run the build that works fine but on the next run it fails and when I check `/etc/sudoers` I see that my change dropped...

What can be the reason and how to make the change work constantly?

Comment: See also [Sudoers file editing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088863/sudoers-file-editing)

Comment: Are you using an *installed* system, as on *live* systems the settings aren't saved and subsequent runs start a new system.

Comment: @Zatigem will the behavior in this case be different if to use `visudo`? I got `Sorry, user <ME> is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/visudo /etc/sudoers' as root on <REMOTE UBUNTU>.`

Comment: @guiverc I use a Jenkins as permanently running service on remote Linux machine. Not a docker Ubuntu image (if you mean that)

Comment: "setup a Jenkins job that need to run an executable file under sudo" Why? I would assume the current method on Ubuntu/Linux would be using a systemd service. I would avoid altering sudoers (my cloud images are all vanilla Ubuntu with 'hooks' to connect to a 2nd (user) partition names /u  with Jenkins installed in /u/opt/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to allow Jenkins to execute script under `sudo` without password prompt I created `/etc/sudoers.d/jenkins` and add this line

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/path/to/script.sh
```